# From string of keys to hash value

Tags: javascript

I have a hash like the one below

```
aa: {
  categories: {
   cat1: 'alpha'
  }
}
```

Starting from the string `'aa.categories.cat1'`, how can I get `alpha` suing plain JS?

Comment: You can use Lodash's [`get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) method

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I'm trying to split and loop through the keys but Ideally, I'd like to find a faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const result = path.split('.').reduce((a, v) => a[v], object);
```

---

Complete snippet:

```js
const object = {
  aa: {
    categories: {
      cat1: 'alpha'
    }
  }
}

const path = 'aa.categories.cat1';

const result = path.split('.').reduce((a, v) => a[v], object);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Array.split" and "Array.reduce" to achieve this

```js
var obj = {
  aa: {
    categories: {
      cat1: 'alpha'
    }
  }
}

function getValue(d) {
  return d.split('.').reduce((o, v) => o[v], obj) 
}

console.log(getValue('aa.categories.cat1'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.